How do I make a token using Token Extensions Metadata in JavaScript/TypeScript?
I know I can make a Token mint with token extensions on the command line with something like:
spl-token initialize-metadata mntTymSqMU4e1NEDdxJ9XoPN4MitCgQ7xxGW6AuRAWQ 'Example token' 'EXMPL' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/opos-asset/main/assets/CompressedCoil/metadata.json

But how do I do this in JS/TS?

I am answering my own question to help others.
There's a example of creating a token using token extensions metadata in the Solana Labs repo. This has been turned into a helper in the @solana-developers/helpers package.
npm i @solana-developers/helpers

Then:
import { makeTokenMint } from  @solana-developers/helpers

Parameters

connection: Connection.
mintAuthority: Keypair of the account that will be given permission to make new tokens.
name: string, name of the token.
symbol: string, like a ticker symbol. Usually in all-caps.
decimals: number, how many decimal places the new token will have.
uri: string, URI to a JSON file containing at minimum a value for image.
additionalMetadata: additional metadata as either Record<string, string> or Array<[string, string]>(optional).
updateAuthority: PublicKey (optional) - public key of the account that can update the token.
freezeAuthority: PublicKey (optional) - public key of the freeze account, default to null

const mintAddress = await makeTokenMint(
  connection,
  mintAuthority,
  "Unit test token",
  "TEST",
  9,
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/professional-education/main/labs/sample-token-metadata.json",
);

